# A question on measurability of stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $\{X_t:t\geq0\}$ be a collection of real-valued random variables with index set $[0,\infty)$. Show that the mapping $t\mapsto X_t$ is Borel-measurable and furthermore if $X_t\in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ for all $t$ then the mapping $t\mapsto E[X_t]$ is Borel-measurable as well.

I am a bit stuck on this so any help is greatly needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We also assume that for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$, we have $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty))\times\mathcal{F}$

Answer (score 1):

Your added assumption is basically saying that the map $\;X: [0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is jointly measurable in $t$ and $\omega$.

To prove the first claim, notice that for any fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, the map $t \mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is the composition of two measurable maps: $$t \stackrel{i_{\omega}}{\longmapsto} (t,\omega) \stackrel{X}{\longmapsto} X(t,\omega)$$ where the inclusion map $i_{\omega}:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty) \times \Omega$ is measurable because its components are measurable, and the map $X:[0,\infty) \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is given to be measurable. Since compositions of measurable maps are measurable, it follows that the map $t \mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is measurable.

For the second part, you want to show that the map $t \mapsto \int_{\Omega}X(t,\omega)\; dP(\omega)$ is measurable. This is the special case of a more general statement in measure theory:

**Claim**: Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space, and let $(Y, \mathcal{B},\mu)$ be a finite measure space. Then for any map $\;f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is $(\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B})$-measurable **and** $\;f(x,\cdot) \in L^1(Y, \mathcal{B},\mu)$ for all $x\in X$, the map $\;I_f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x \mapsto \int_Y f(x,y)\;d\mu(y)$ is measurable.

**Proof sketch of claim**: Prove it first when $\;f=1_{A \times B}$ for some $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}$ (this should be easy). Then the set $\{E \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}: I_{1_E}$ is measurable$\}$ is a Dynkin-system which contains a $\pi$-system which generates $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$, and thus $\{E \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}: I_{1_E}$ is measurable$\} = \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$, so the claim is proved when $\;f=1_E$ for some $E \in \mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B}$. Now extend to all non-negative measurable $f$ by approximating from below by simple functions and using MCT; and then extend to all $f$ such that $f(x,\cdot) \in L^1$ by considering positive and negative parts. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful but am still not sure how to show $i_\omega$ is measurable. What you mean by components? Do you mean the entries of the ordered pair? And just to check as $1_{A\times B}=1_A1_B$, so $\int_Y1_{A\times B}d\mu=\mu(B)1._A$ and that is why it is measurable?

Comment: The map $i_{\omega}$ is a mapping into a product, so one just needs to check that the individual component functions (yes, the entries in the ordered pair) are measurable. This is true because the first entry is the identity on $[0,\infty)$, and the second entry is the the constant map $t \mapsto \omega$.

Comment: One has that $1_{A \times B}(x,y) = 1_A(x)1_B(y)$, so yes it is true that $\int_Y 1_{A \times B}(x,y)\;d\mu(y) = \mu(B)1_A(x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I see it now and the problem I had was not knowing what is exactly meant measurable mapping into a product. So just to check a map $f: X\rightarrow Y\times Z$ defined by $f(x)=(g(x),h(x))$ is measurable from $X$ into the product $Y\times Z$ iff $g$ and $h$ are measurable mappings from $X$ to $Y$ resp. $Z$? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks again hope you don't mind me asking but 2 other questions that occurred to me. So if $X_t$ is progressively measurable then $X_t$ is adapted and to show this we use the same reasoning you gave to show $t\mapsto X_t$ is measurable? Also is $\int_0^tX_udu$ also then progressively measurable and if so how would you show it (of course we assume that the Riemann integral exists)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by progressively measurable. You should maybe ask this as a separate question.

Comment: $X_t$ is progressively I think your claim will also answer th

Comment: It's fine I think your claim answers that question as well as $ X_t $ is progressively measurable, iff for all $t$,  $X_t$ is $\mathcal{B}[0,t]\times\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable

Comment: @Johan: Yes the basic idea of the argument is the same, but to show that $X_t$ is adapted, you're now using the other variable, i.e, you're showing that for fixed $t$, the map $\omega \mapsto X(t,\omega)$ is measurable by considering the composition $\omega \mapsto (t,\omega) \mapsto X(t,\omega)$.

Comment: If the process is riemann integrable, then one can show that $\int_0^t X_udu$ is measurable by writing it as a limit of Riemann sums and then showing that the individual Riemann sums are progressively measurable.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be true. Let $\Omega$ be a one-point probability space and $D\subseteq[0,\infty)$ be non-measurable.  For each $t\ge 0$, put
$X_t(\omega) = 1$ if $t\in D$ and $0$ otherwise.  All of the $X_t$ are measurable, but $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not and neither is $t\mapsto E(X_t)$.

Comment: Thank you for your input and my apologies but I left out an assumption which I assume now is pertinent, namely  that for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ we have $X^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{B}([0,\infty)]\times\mathcal{F}$. With this information can you show me how I can show the other statements?